# Vue cli image wont load with webpack

Tags: vue.js, webpack

#### What am I doing?

I am using the intersection observer API to make lazy loading.

#### What have I tried?

I tried the code in a simple HTML page and it works perfect, but when I use the code in vue, the images won't load (local images). If I put a htttp source images (online images) it works perfect, too. I think this is a webpack error config. Am I right? How can I fix it?.

#### Whats the error?

When i use a local image the code doesnt work, if only change that src with something else like this image https://images.pexels.com/photos/69817/france-confectionery-raspberry-cake-fruit-69817.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940 the code WORKS, why i cant make it work with local images?

#### HTML AND SCRIPT

```
<template>
    <div class="container" id="section3">
        <span class="containerTitle">Galeria</span>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <img v-lazyload data-src="@assets/images/001.jpg" class="card">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import lazyload from '../directives/lazyload'
export default {
    directives:{
      lazyload
    },   
}
</script>
```

#### DIRECTIVE

```
export default{
    inserted: el =>{
        const options = {
            // root:
            rootMargin: '0px 0px 0px 0px',
            threshold:1
        }
        var observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries,observer) =>{
            entries.forEach(entry => {
                if(entry.isIntersecting){
                    el.src = el.dataset.src
                    observer.unobserve(el)
                    console.log('intersecting');
                    
                }
            })
            },options) 
            observer.observe(el) 
    }
}
```

**CODE IMAGE**

[image]

**FOLDER**

[image]

Comment: Please include code as text instead of images

Comment: my bad,updated @Phil

Comment: The easiest way is to put your images inside the `public` folder (perhaps in a subfolder) and then use absolute URLs in the `data-src` attribute(s). Read the manual - https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#url-transform-rules

Comment: i have all the images in the /assets folder @IVOGELOV

Comment: Well, then perhaps this blog post will help you - https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/lazy-load-vue-components-when-they-become-visible/

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the directory you're working in with the folders expanded?

Comment: hello @Bram post updated, im sure its not a path error, but there is the image

Comment: @AlexHunter see the answer I've given.

Comment: Did you tried `src='require("image path")'`?

Comment: yes,not work. the error comes with webpack, theres something in the config thats preventing the image to show, but i just post the solution

Answer (score -2, accepted):

doing extensive research i found this article about vuejs and static assets.

https://edicasoft.com/weblog/2018/04/27/static-vs-srcassets-webpack-template-vue-cli/

They said that this kind of problems occurs "because" of webpack,like i though, so the solution for this (i hope not the only solution), but this is the solution so far...

**QUOTE**

All asset URLs such as , background: url(...) and CSS @import  are resolved by Webpack as module dependencies like require('./logo.png').

We then use loaders for Webpack, such as file-loader and url-loader, to process them. Webpack template has already configured these loaders.

File-loader helps to determine the final file location and how to name it using version hashes for better caching. Thus you can put your static assets near your .vue files and use relative paths. There is no need to put them strictly into the ‘assets’ folder.

Url-loader helps to conditionally inline assets such as base64 data URL, reducing the amount of HTTP requests.

So what the hell should I do with it?

**The answer is: put  your assets  in the ‘src’ folder.**

I tested this and it works perfect **BUT** you **CANT** make a subfolder and this for me, is disorganized.

This is the final folder structure to get this done using intersection observer api as vue **directive!**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your image path.

1. You can fix it with either using public folder and give it in path.
2. You can also check for auto suggestion which come up while typing, this may help you to check whether your path is correct or not.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKbBr.png)

Comment: Hi!
1. The assets is a public folder too, by the way i put the image in /public for testing, not working either

Comment: Try this syntax:- ` <img v-lazy="img.src" >`

Comment: hi, if try that syntax the lazyload.js will not work, as you can see i use the path in the dara-src and copy to src

Comment: I guess your data-src is not accepting the file. It is difficult to say what is causing. Perhaps this page might help you :-  [link](https://css-tricks.com/lazy-loading-images-with-vue-js-directives-and-intersection-observer/)

Answer (score 2):

Your path is wrong. You gave `../assets/images/001.jpg` as the path to the image (as stated in your question), but according to your directory tree it's `../assets/001.jpg` (or write it like `@/assets/001.jpg`, `@` points to root of project). That should fix it.

Comment: Hi @bram i updated the post images and code, and no, its not the path. By the way i tested like you told and i got the same "error", i tested too with an http image and it work!

Comment: Please specify your 'error' in your question. More information means easier for someone to give an answer to you.

Comment: I just updated the post with that, thank you @Bram i think is a webpack error, because if use simple js without vue it works

Comment: @AlexHunter does the console print any error ? Like `resource not found` or smilar?.

Comment: no, it just dont show up, but if i change to the image on the internet, works perfect @Bram

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember you can't use `@` sign inside `<template>`. 
So you can either:

### require it

`<img v-lazyload :data-src="require('@assets/images/001.jpg')" class="card">`

### import it

```
<template>
...
<img v-lazyload data-src="image" class="card">
...
</template>
<script>
import img from '@assets/images/001.jpg';
...
data() {
  return {
    image: img,
  }
}
...
</script>
```

### use relative path

`<img v-lazyload data-src="../assets/images/001.jpg" class="card">`

You can check how it works in [Vue docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling)

Comment: hi @Qback im using a relative path and thats why im having this error (i think) because if i use this image https://images.pexels.com/photos/69817/france-confectionery-raspberry-cake-fruit-69817.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940 the code works perfectly

Comment: I mean, maybe try to use `require` syntax like `<img v-lazyload :data-src="require('@assets/images/001.jpg')" class="card">`

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember why this works, but you need to use the following syntax:

```
<img v-lazyload data-src="~assets/images/001.jpg" class="card">
```

with the `~` replacing the `../`.

I will update the answer if I figure out exactly why.

Comment: Hi,i updated the post images and code, and no, its not the path. By the way i tested like you told and i got the same "error", i tested too with an http image and it work!